# D3 Adding data to 3D Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Below is my js code from a D3 example found [here](http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/9994181).

```
var MsaSubGroup  = svg.append("g").attr("id","MsaSubGroupData").attr("class","pieChart");
Donut3D.draw("MsaSubGroupData", getData(MSA), 450, 150, 130, 100, 30, 0.4);

var wedges = MsaSubGroup.selectAll("g.slices").data(datum).enter();
        wedges.on("mousemove", function(d){ //This is what the browser is complaining about.
            mousex = d3.mouse(this);
            mousex = mousex[0];
            //console.log(d);
            d3.select(this)
                .classed("hover", true);

            tooltip.html(d.label+": " + d.value).style("visibility", "visible").style("left", mousex + "px" );
        });
```

I have made a few modification to try and add data along with a tool tip. Seemed pretty straight forward in the fact that I just needed to bind the data to the svg. However, I am getting curious error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

What exactly is undefined? When I console.log(datum) I can see the array of objects being returned, so what am I doing wrong?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Which line is causing the error? And what is `getData`?

Comment: @Oleg getData is function that returns the data. That is not line that is causing the problem. It is the wedges.on("mousemove", function(d){ line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `wedges` is the result of the [`enter()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#enter) call which:

> only defines the `append`, `insert`, `select` and `call` operators

So it doesn't have any `on` method and this is what's causing the *"undefined is not a function"* error.

I'm assuming you want either:

```
var wedges = MsaSubGroup
        .selectAll("g.slices")
        .on('mousemove', ...);

wedges.data(myData).enter()...
```

or

```
var wedges = MsaSubGroup
        .selectAll("g.slices")
        .data(myData)
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .on('mousemove', ...);
```

Comment: Tres bien, merci beaucoup! Would not mind a thumbs up if you thought the question might help others with this issue. You made a good point.